Stuck on Running Tests
Does anyone knows why are my test not running? or visible not running?
I can see that "something" is happening, but after a while (1h or more...) nothing is shown besides:
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------- 
[INFO]  T E S T S 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------- 
[INFO] Running users.UserInTest 
22:39:43.174 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.Suite - [config] classpath:karate-config.js 
22:39:43.183 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.Suite - waiting for 3 features to complete

Any hint on what might be happening?
I created the test trough maven archetype karate api, and didn't change anything on pom.xml.
karate-config.js wasn't touched also.
The only thing I did, was delete the example file, that btw, it wasn't working also - same kind of problem.
I replicated the structure to my needs for testing an API.
Thanks in advance
No ideas of what I should try to do to fix this.

Karate 1.4.1 and below has a problem with Java version 22 and this looks like it - and unfortunately things just hang and there is nothing in the log.
The solution is to use Karate 1.5.0.RC4 or downgrade your Java version.
Note that this karate-todo example has a karate-1.5 branch that will work for Java 22, follow this link: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-todo/tree/karate-1.5
